# Is Leonard a Whispered?

Tags: full-metal-panic

**Spoilers for FMP The Second Raid**

Is Leonard a Whispered like

> his twin sister Tessa? If so, do we know his specialty? If not, how did he become the leader of the opposition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think some of this is not revealed in TSR, so I've spoilered it.

> Yes, he is a Whispered. Not only that, he exceeds his sister's abilities both physically and mentally, and he used his knowledge to produce Arm Slaves for Amalgam. I don't think we know for sure how/why he became the leader of the opposition, though it's implied at some point that primarily he wanted more freedom.

Source: [Wiki](http://fullmetalpanic.wikia.com/wiki/Leonard_Testarossa)

Answer (score 3):

Leonard Testarossa is indeed a Whispered.

> His specialty is Arm Slave design. He is the one who designed the miniature AS Alastor units and his own personal AS, Belial. Though not explicitly stated it's very likely he designed the Codarl (aka Venom), Behemoth, and Eligor as well. His ultimate goal is to change history to create his own ideal world, a world without pain and suffering. In this ideal world, the Whispered would not exist. Whispered children like him would not be captured and tortured as the Black Technology would not exist, wars would not exist, all the people that would have died would now be alive. He believes all the suffering he causes to get there does not matter, since it would not exist in the world he wants to create.

Amalgam's main goal is to consolidate the power of the Whispered. The power hierarchy structure of Amalgam is akin to that of a web, making it impossible to topple, but easy to subvert.

> Leonard is ultimately a traitor to the goal of the organization and use their resources to further his goal. He goes about doing this by taking out the higher ranking members of Amalgam, so that all the resources will come to be under his control. He's able to use charisma to win many people over to his side (like Kalinin). Among his goals, he wants a list of all the people involved in Amalgam, the ones who allowed it to turn into a malicious organization that it is now, so that they could be taken care of in the creation of the ideal world.